# Joining two tables with foreign keys - Hibernate, SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a *`User`* table and a *`Book`* table that I would like to connect.

User can rent many books and one book can be rented from many users.

It's *`many-to-many`* relationship. If I am right?

So I created third table *`Borrow`* that has foreign key (*`bookId, userId`*).

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Borrow> borrow;
    
    //getters and setters
```

**Book.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Books")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "book_id")
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private String ISBN;
    private String author;
    private String issuer;
    private Integer dateOfIssue;
    private Boolean IsRented;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Borrow> borrow;
    //getters and setters
```

**Borrow.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Borrows")
public class Borrow {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private Date takenDate;
    private Date broughtDate;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="bookId")
    private Book book;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="userId")
    private User user;
```

When I am trying to display details of Borrow table using a Postman I only get it's `id`, `takenDate`, `broughtDate` I don't get to see `userId` or `bookId`.

This is JSON that I get back after running GET method on Postman

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "takenDate": "2020-08-04T00:36:07.000+00:00",
        "broughtDate": "2020-08-02T00:36:07.000+00:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "takenDate": "2020-08-11T00:36:07.000+00:00",
        "broughtDate": "2020-07-05T00:36:07.000+00:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "takenDate": "2020-08-21T00:38:00.000+00:00",
        "broughtDate": "2020-08-12T00:38:00.000+00:00"
    }
]
```

Code to get all items:

```
 @GetMapping("/items")
    public List<Borrow> getAllItems(){
        return service.getAllItems();
    }
```

I don't understand why foreign keys and it's values are not displayed?
Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. You use ***@JsonIgnore*** in your Borrow entity. The columns with JsonIgnore will be ignored when serializing an object to JSON.
2. You use ***Lazy Loading(FetchType.LAZY)*** in your Borrow entity. If you don't use JsonIgnore, you have to load all other entities (Book and User) of Borrow entity in your service or you have to use FetchType.EAGER.

Comment: I use @JsonIgnore so that some data are not displayed when I don't want them to be displayed. I changed it to FetchType.EAGER but nothing changed.

Comment: With JsonIgnore in Borrow entity you don‘t have any columns of Book and User entities in json. If you hide some informations you can use your values in DTO.

Comment: When I removed @JsonIgnore I got to see the details that I wanted but also infinite loop (I have two users and two books who are now being displayed infinite) and this `error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed`